# SQL wont work when mixing it in controller action

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to make some filters work, but I don't know why is it breaking.

I'm trying to filter my Pins table in the `:min_price` column:

In the controller action, I do:

```
@pins = Pin.where(min_price: 'BETWEEN' params[:pin][:min_value] 'AND' params[:pin][:max_value])
```

I don't know how to make this statement with no sintax errors. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use plain SQL

```
@pins = Pin.where('min_price BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:pin][:min_value], params[:pin][:max_value])
```

Comment: Worked as a charm. Thanks!